# Integrating a multiple regression equation (including covariates) into ggplot2 graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, regression, visualization

I am currently generating simple linear regression plots in ggplot2 with the following code (toy example)

```
library(ggplot2)

Data<-data.frame(Age=c(40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49),
                 Height=c(185,184,183,182,181,186,187,188,189,190),
                 Sex=c("Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female"),
                 Weight=c(84,83,82,81,80,85,86,87,88,89),
                 BMI=c(20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29))

points<-c("#FF9999","turquoise")
lines<-c("dark red","blue")
linetypes<-c(1,1)

x<-ggplot(Data,aes(x=Age,y=Weight))+
  geom_point(aes(fill=factor(Sex)),size=4,alpha=1,shape=21,color="transparent")+
  geom_smooth(aes(color=Sex,linetype=Sex),method="lm",formula=y~x,lwd=1,se=F)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=points,labels=c("Female","Male"))+
  scale_colour_manual(values=lines)+
  scale_linetype_manual(values=linetypes)+
  theme_classic(base_size=15)+
  theme(legend.position="top",legend.direction="horizontal")+
  labs(fill="Points",colour="Lines",x='Age',y='Weight')+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(shape=c(16,16),alpha=1,size=4,color=c("#FF9999","turquoise"))))+
  guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes=list(linetype=c(1,1),alpha=1,size=1,color=c("dark red","blue"))))+
  guides(linetype="none")
x
```

I am stuck as how to add one-or-more covariates, in order to transform the plots from simple to multiple linear regression, e.g., from
**Weight~Age** to **Weight~Age+Height+BMI**

I am sure that it must have something to do with the *method="lm"* and *formula=y~x* commands, but I am not clear on exactly what changes need to be made.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

[image: example]

Comment: Your problem is not so much with the code, but the concept. Each covariate in a regression adds a _dimension_ onto the final result. A regression in the form of `y~x` represents a line fitted to points on a plane. A regression in the form of `y~x+z` represents the best fitting _plane_ through a 3 dimensional cloud of points. Your formula, with three independent variables, implies that you are looking for the best 3D volume in a 4D cloud of points. You cannot easily show this in a 2 dimensional plot. What would the axes be? What would the result look like?

Comment: But the bottom line is that `geom_smooth` cannot take formulae with more than one independent variable for that reason. You need other tricks to show your regression result, such as plotting one variable at a time against the mean of covariates, multiple lines showing the effect of one changing one of the regressors, using color to indicate one of the regressors, or using facets for categorical variables.

Comment: [See if this gives you ideas on how you might visualize your model.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggiraphExtra/vignettes/ggPredict.html)

Comment: @AllanCameron thank you both for your feedback. This has helped me to better-understand how to deal with covariates, both graphically and mathematically.

Comment: @Kat thank you both for your feedback. This has helped me to better-understand how to deal with covariates, both graphically and mathematically,